# PHP - CURL strange behaviour while setting headers

Tags: php, curl, header

I have written a function in PHP to send a CURl request. 
The code is given below.

```
function curl_post($url,$fields,$headers=[],$connect_timeout = 3,$timeout =  20) {
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    $postvars = '';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
        $postvars .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
    } 

    $postvars = trim($postvars,'&');
    $postvars = json_encode($fields);


    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);                //0 for a get request
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postvars);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,$connect_timeout);

    curl_setopt($ch,$timeout, 20);
    $refined_headers = [];
    if(sizeof($headers)) {
        foreach($headers as $name => $value) {
            $refined_headers[] = "'".$name.": ".$value."'"; 
        }


        print_r($refined_headers); 
        //$refined_headers = ['Content-Type: application/json'];
        //echo $refined_headers;exit;
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$refined_headers);




    }
    $response = curl_exec($ch);


    $info = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    print_r($info);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

So I called the function like this

```
$url = API_ENDPOINT.$method.'/';

$response = curl_post($url,$params_to_send,$headers);
echo $response;
```

where $url contains my API url and $params contain the parameters as associative array and $headers as follows

```
$headers = ['Content-Type'=>'application/json'];
```

My problem is that, the content type header is setting. But when I manually set it inside the curl_post function like

```
$refined_headers = ['Content-Type: application/json']
```

it is working perfectly. 
What is the problem with my code.

Comment: `['Content-Type'=>'application/json'];`  is not equal to `['Content-Type: application/json']`  check quotes

Comment: The following lines already does that..
 foreach($headers as $name => $value) {
            $refined_headers[] = "'".$name.": ".$value."'"; 
        }

Since it didn't work, I put it manually

Comment: i mean to say that what you are  doing like this:- `$headers = ['Content-Type'=>'application/json'];` which is not working. change that to  `$headers = ['Content-Type:application/json'];`

Comment: Dude .. That is the input tp my own function, which is converted to the format as you said inside the function.. I mean my function takes associative array as arguments. Then while creating the request, it converts it to the format needed for curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. The problem was
I put two single quotes before and after the header, which was not needed

```
$refined_headers[] = "'".$name.": ".$value."'";
```

I changed that to the following and the issueis resolved.

```
$refined_headers[] = $name.": ".$value;
```